# Transform Java-project to .NET-project

Tags: java, .net

I have a project in Java. I want transform it to .NET-project.

How to do it the easiest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a look on [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/). This is a JVM and Java compiler implementation in .NET.

With this you can recompile your project under .NET and then replace calls to Java libraries with appropriate calls to .NET libraries without breaking all the app.

Comment: I use IKVM for RMI between a java app and a .net app, but would not consider it suitable for migrating a java app. It adds a huge extra layer of indirection and makes debugging mighty difficult (you would not believe how many times I was stepping through something on the .net side only to have the thread of execution seemingly vanish in mid-air on me).

Comment: The same is for debugging mixed .NET and managed code...

BTW, as far as I understand term "migration", it's moving away from old codebase. It's a bit simpler IMHO then the task of coexistence you had at hand.